# Protected sheet + hidden fornula = clear values when entering cell

Tags: excel, office-2013

I have an issue when creating a new excel workbook with protected sheets. When the user double clicks a non-locked cell (with hidden formula) the value is cleared. On unprotected sheets the value remains and  the cursor is set to the end of the cell. Are there any workaround this issue?

Comment: The "workaround" is: Do not hide the formula. What do you expect, what Excel should do if you set: The cell is editable but the formula, which is the cell content, is hidden?

Comment: If you really must hide the formula (proprietary model, etc.) you should create a user-defined function and put it in a password-protected VBA project.  Then your cell will simply say "=MyCustomFunction(X,Y,Z)" and you don't have to hide it.  The added benefit to this is that is more robust and even more difficult for a user to work around.

Comment: The reason for hiding the formula is to prevent users from overwriting existing formatting and formulas in the worksheet when copying content/data from other workbooks. + I don't want to add VBA code to the workbook because the workbook is going to be sent on mail to the customers and many companies have email scanners that blocks workbooks with VBA projects.

Comment: If the reason is to prevent users from overwriting existing formulas, then why is the cell which contains the formula editable and not locked?

Answer (score 0):

If there are merged cells in a range the cell protection may fail, causing the described phenomenon (only hidden formulas will work without the cell protection).
In this case you have 2 options:

1. Unmerge the cells  and then the protection will work.
2. Define separate protection ranges for merged cells and unmerged cells.

For example:  You try to lock and hide formulas in column "A"  but cells A1 to B1 are merged. As a result column "A" will not be protected but the formulas will be hidden.  If you try to edit them The cells will be erased and you will get no warning for locked cells.